# Eisenstein-like series with odd weight

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

It is known that Eisenstein series has a Fourier expansion
$$
G_{k}(\tau)=-\frac{B_{k}}{2k}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sigma_{k-1}(n)q^{n}
$$
where $\sigma_{k-1}(n)=\sum_{d|n}d^{k-1}$ if $k\geq 4$ is even. For $k=2$, this is not a modular form, but it is a quasi-modular form in some sense.

Question : For odd $k\geq 5$, does $G_{k}$ defined as above has any interesting automorphic property? (In this case, $B_{k}=0$ and it might be something like cusp form.)

Comment: For odd $k$, Eisenstein series vanish...

Comment: @ayberk I know, if we follow the original definition $G_{k}=\sum_{\gamma\in \Gamma_{\infty}\backslash \Gamma_{1}}1|_{k}\gamma$. But if we define Eisenstein series of odd weight as Fourier series it does not vanish.

Comment: They satisfy so called holomorphic quantum modularity. See for example this talk of Don Zagier's. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Rj_xh3UKrU&t=1778s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, see

Shun Shimomura 
Modularity gap for Eisenstein series
Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci.
Volume 86, Number 4 (2010), 79-84.

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1270127451

Comment: I don't know why but I just saw this now... thank you!